# Как сделать глобальным объект получаемый по const ссылке

Tags: c++, const

В функцию передается const ссылка, например:

```
void someFun(const Objtype& object){}
```

Как сделать доступным получаемый объект для других функций, не передавая его каждый раз. Т.е. я хочу сделать его глобальным,что-то  вроде следующего:

```
Objtype globalobject;

void someFun(Objtype& object){
   globalobject = object;
}

void someFun1(){
   globalobject.getSomeData();
}

void someFun2(){
   globalobject.getSomeData();
}
```

Как это сделать если я получаю const Objtype& ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть два вопроса. Вам нужна копия или ссылка на тот же объект? Можно ли скопировать объект?

Нужна копия + можно скопировать:

```
Object global;
voif foo(const Object &object){
    global = object;
}
```

Нужна копия + нельзя скопировать:
Тут, увы, никак

Нужна ссылка:
Ссылки нельзя оставлять не инициализированными или перенацеливать. Поэтому вместо ссылки следует взять указатель:

```
const Object *global;
voif foo(const Object &object){
    global = &object;
}
```

Если вам нужно изменять состояние этого объекта, то можно сделать так:

```
Object *global;
voif foo(const Object &object){
    global = const_cast<Object*>(&object);
}
```

Но это скользкая дорожка. Если изменять объект, который изначально передавали как неизменяемый, то можно получить трудноуловимый баг на этапе выполнения.

Comment: Изменение объекта, полученного по const_cast - не баг, а UB

Comment: А если пошаманить?

Comment: @gbg, если мне не изменяет память, то UB это снятие константности с констант. А снятие константности со ссылок и указателей на объекты, которые не были константами изначально это вполне законные операции.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: Но если объект передан как const, с хорошими шансами он реально const.

Comment: @VladD, тем не менее применение `const_cast` само по себе не является UB, а лишь в конкретных случаях.

Comment: @ixSci: В любом случае `const_cast` — нарушение инкапсуляции. Процедуре нужно знать, что оно-то const, но не const, шизофрения какая-то.

Comment: @VladD, необязательно. Есть случаи когда ты точно знаешь, что константность снимать можно. В моей практике была одна необходимость снимать константность.

Comment: @ixSci: Если это так, зачем передавать в функцию `const`? Ну и сразу получается tight coupling: метод нужно обязательно вызывать с не-const-объектом. То есть это катит как костыль, но не как архитектурно верное решение.

Comment: @VladD, тем не менее, бывает, что так нужно. Хорошее это или плохое решение — вопрос дискуссионный. Иногда, видимо, проще сделать const_cast, чем что-то другое.

Comment: @VladD, пример хорошего снятия константности описан у Майерса в третьем правиле Effectve C. Можно снимать константность с возвращаемого значения, чтобы избежать дублирования кода. Хотя, конечно, к тому что делает ТС это не имеет никакого отношения:)

Answer (score 2):

Ненавижу глобальные переменные :) Поэтому - вот вариант:

```
const ObjectType& single(const ObjectType * o = nullptr)
{
    static const ObjectType *obj = nullptr;
    if (o) obj = o;
    return *obj;
}

void someFun(const ObjectType& object)
{
    // ...
    single(&object);
}
```

Далее, чтоб получить - просто вызвать `single()`.

Но! это все ***очень стремные*** игры. Представьте себе, что в `someFun` мы передаем временный объект. Дальше не пояснять?...

Или:

```
int i = 5;
someFun(i);
i = 6;
cout << single() << endl;
```

Вот вам и `const`. Словом, сделать можно почти всё. Вопрос - зачем? Проблемы могут очень легко перевесить преимущества.